# Objective-C Library - cannot form weak reference to instance of class

Tags: objective-c, osx-lion

I'm currently working with the XMPP Library for Objective-C, and I'm using the "Desktop" example code.

It logs in fine; however, when I open a new chat, or someone sends me a message, it crashes.

This seems like where something goes wrong:

```
XMPPStream[11678:1b03] RECV: 
2012-06-05 15:03:59:379 XMPPStream[11678:1b03] RECV: 
2012-06-05 15:03:59:382 XMPPStream[11678:403] RosterController: xmppRosterDidChange:
2012-06-05 15:03:59:387 XMPPStream[11678:403] RosterController: xmppRosterDidChange:
2012-06-05 15:04:01:900 XMPPStream[11678:403] tableView:shouldEditTableColumn:"jid" row:0
2012-06-05 15:04:01:900 XMPPStream[11678:403] user: 
objc[11678]: cannot form weak reference to instance (0x7fcd4a498930) of class ChatController
```

and

```
objc[11998]: cannot form weak reference to instance (0x7f853bd17c70) of class ChatController
(lldb) 
(lldb)
```

What does "Cannot form weak reference to instance....of class ChatController" mean? Do you guys know how I can fix it? I used an older version of this code with Snow Leopard and it worked, Lion is screwing me up!

Thank you!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looking at [Mike Ash's blog](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html), I found an interesting paragraph:

> ARC's implementation of zeroing weak references requires close
>   coordination between the Objective-C reference counting system and the
>   zeroing weak reference system. This means that any class which
>   overrides retain and release can't be the target of a zeroing weak
>   reference. While this is uncommon, some Cocoa classes, like NSWindow,
>   suffer from this limitation. Fortunately, if you hit one of these
>   cases, you will know it immediately, as your program will crash with a
>   message like this:
>
> ```
> objc[2478]: cannot form weak reference to instance (0x10360f000) of class NSWindow
> ```
>
> If you really must make a weak reference to classes such as these, you
>   can use the __unsafe_unretained qualifier in place of __weak.

Did you turn ARC on in your app?  If you turn it off, do you get better results?

Answer (score 7):

In my project (as a mistake) there was a weak reference to `self` in `dealloc` (it was a separate method, called to clear used resource). 
Using weak reference to one property of this object (that captured just a reference to the resource) solved the problem.

It is really strange to create weak reference to half-destroyed object in `dealloc`.

## NEVER WRITE LIKE THIS:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    [self freeUsedResource];
}

- (void) freeUsedResource
{
    __weak MyClass *weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{

        [weakSelf.usedResource freeUsedMemory];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remember that you need to comment two places.

```
@interface GCDMulticastDelegateNode : NSObject
{
//#if __has_feature(objc_arc_weak)
//__weak id delegate;
//#else
__unsafe_unretained id delegate;
//#endif

dispatch_queue_t delegateQueue;
 }

 - (id)initWithDelegate:(id)delegate delegateQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)delegateQueue;

 //#if __has_feature(objc_arc_weak)
 //@property (/* atomic */ readwrite, weak) id delegate;
 //#else
 @property (/* atomic */ readwrite, unsafe_unretained) id delegate;
 //#endif

 @property (nonatomic, readonly) dispatch_queue_t delegateQueue;

 @end
```